# Magento 2 - Transactional E-Mail Template location

Tags: magento2, transactional-mail

I need to change the code of a transactional E-Mail template.

Where can I find them in the magento project so I can change them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All transactional email templates are stored in the

```
email
```

directory of Magento_Sales module. If you have installed Magento through composer, then below is the directory to look for.

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/email
```

Here is the link of the [path](https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Sales/view/frontend/email)

You can simply copy the file and paste it in your theme directory to include all your customization.